# How to sync user data across systems?

Tags: rsync, users, accounts

We have 3 family laptops and I'd like to sync the accounts between them. Since they are laptops and move around, I can't use an `nfs` client/server architecture. From what I (poorly) understand of NIS or IAR, they sync the credentials, not the data. I don't care about that, I can edit 2 lines in `/etc/passwd~shadow` if need be.

Currently I use `rsync -a --delete root@laptop1:/home/user/ root@laptop2:/home/user` manually whenever one laptop changes hand (that doesn't happen too often), the drawback is that I need root ssh access (never a good idea) and it's dicey to not make mistakes (the accounts must be logged off at both ends, the direction good, etc...)

Any suggestions for improvements ?